# Does Link Between World's Hero Mode impact the street pass battles?

Tags: streetpass, zelda-link-between-worlds

Does any aspect of a Hero Mode game affect the street pass battle feature of Link Between Worlds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this article](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/711412-the-legend-of-zelda-a-link-between-worlds/faqs/68297?print=2#section2) on [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com):

> > Hero Mode:
>
> It doesn't matter, whether the file is in Hero Mode or not. You can
>   receive Shadow Links from a normal game in a Hero Mode file and vice
>   versa. Only your name, equipment and medal count will be transmitted.
>   However, the Shadow Links will deal four times the damage in Hero
>   Mode. A purple potion for example causes 32 hearts of damage on you...
>   You will only deal normal damage on them, so be prepared.

Comment: So if you are in hero mode, you are effectively weaker when fighting as Link, but your Shadow Links that are sent from a Hero mode file aren't affected in any way?

Comment: @StuperUser - Yes.  From what I understand, that is correct.